# How to draw text on an image and save it using UWP (for Windows 10)

Tags: c#, uwp, draw

I want to draw text on a template image in UWP (for Windows 10), and then be able to save the image (so the user could print or share it).

I have played around with the canvas control and even the Win2D package from nuget. Any suggestions as to what the best way to do this are appreciated. Sample code of where I left off is below.

**XAML**

```
<Page
x:Class="DrawTextExample.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:DrawTextExample"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:canvas="using:Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Xaml"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button Name="btnSaveImage" Content="Save the image" Margin="10" Click="btnSaveImage_Click" />

    <Grid Name="MyCreatedImage">
        <Image Name="imgName" Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="Assets/HelloMyNameIs.jpg" />
        <TextBlock Name="lblName" Text="McFly" Margin="20,100,20,20" FontSize="36"/>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

**Code Behind**

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;

namespace DrawTextExample {
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void btnSaveImage_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e) {
            var bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
            await bitmap.RenderAsync(MyCreatedImage);
        }
    }
}
```

**Image (HelloMyNameIs.jpg)**
[image: Hello my name is]

Comment: You didn't just draw white text on a white image background?

Comment: No, the image provided above is referenced in the code, so i included it to ensure that all parts are available. When I run the program, the TextBlock called lblName has the text "McFly" appear as black text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to draw text on a template image in UWP (for Windows 10), and then be able to save the image (so the user could print or share it).

According to your code snippet, you are trying to use [`RenderTargetBitmap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.RenderTargetBitmap) which can meet your requirements. This class can render the `Image` with the `TextBlock`  together into one image. Your code snippet just lack of saving. You can save the rendered image as follows:

```
private async void btnSaveImage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RenderTargetBitmap bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
    await bitmap.RenderAsync(MyCreatedImage);

    var pixelBuffer = await bitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
    var pixels = pixelBuffer.ToArray();
    var displayInformation = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();
    StorageFolder pictureFolder = KnownFolders.SavedPictures;
    var file = await pictureFolder.CreateFileAsync("test2.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
    {
        var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, stream);
        encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                             BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied,
                             (uint)bitmap.PixelWidth,
                             (uint)bitmap.PixelHeight,
                             displayInformation.RawDpiX,
                             displayInformation.RawDpiY,
                             pixels);
        await encoder.FlushAsync();
    }
}
```

You may also try to use [Win2D](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D) which may be recommended. You can draw images, draw text and draw shapes as you want. It provides the [`CanvasBitmap.SaveAsync`](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/M_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasBitmap_SaveAsync_3.htm) method for saving the result. For example,  the following demo showed how to draw the text on the image and save it to the picture folder.

```
Uri imageuri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/HelloMyNameIs.jpg");
StorageFile inputFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(imageuri);
BitmapDecoder imagedecoder;
using (var imagestream = await inputFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
{
    imagedecoder =await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(imagestream);
}  
CanvasDevice device = CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice();
CanvasRenderTarget renderTarget = new CanvasRenderTarget(device, imagedecoder.PixelWidth, imagedecoder.PixelHeight, 96);
using (var ds = renderTarget.CreateDrawingSession())
{
    ds.Clear(Colors.White);
    CanvasBitmap image = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(device, inputFile.Path, 96);
    ds.DrawImage(image);
    ds.DrawText(lblName.Text, new System.Numerics.Vector2(150, 150), Colors.Black);
}
string filename = "test1.png";
StorageFolder pictureFolder = KnownFolders.SavedPictures;
var file = await pictureFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
using (var fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
    await renderTarget.SaveAsync(fileStream, CanvasBitmapFileFormat.Png, 1f);
}
```

If you want personality text drawing on the image you may consider using `InkCanvas` to [DrawInk](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/M_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasDrawingSession_DrawInk.htm). Details you may reference [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43390816/uwp-how-can-i-attach-an-image-to-an-inkcanvas).

Comment: Both solutions work nicely! I did have to make a minor change to the second solution so that the filename had the JPG extension, and to the CanvasBitmapFileFormat so it was also using JPG as the format.

Comment: Thanks. How to set font size? How to rotate text? How to determine the image dimensions according to dynamic text? How to add a new line and make the text display in 2 lines?

Comment: @SurenSaluka, please try to resolve these issues by check the Win2D sample. If you still have issues you could ask a new thread to detail your issues.