# UWP: Is there a upper limit that the instance of InkCanvas can be created?

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

In a UWP project, I put an `InkCanvas` in each ListViewItem. But when the items count exceed 126, I got an XamlParseException, which complained: 
*Cannot create instance of type `'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.InkCanvas`'*

Below is the naïve code snippets:

```
<Page x:Class="App9.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items, Mode=OneWay}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <InkCanvas />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

code behind:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<int> Items { get;  }
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.Items = new ObservableCollection<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 130; i++)
        {
            this.Items.Add(i);
        }
        InitializeComponent();

    }
}
```

(Please note: to test the upper limit, I've changed the default `ItemsPanel` of ListView)
These above code is pretty simple, so it seems nothing is wrong with the code. Could it be there is a upper limit one can create `InkCanvas`?

**Edit**:
I've tested to create the InkCanvas in code behind like this:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 130; i++)
    {
        this.lvw.Items.Add(new InkCanvas());
    }
```

which I got a different runtime error:
***System.OutOfMemoryException***: 'Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.'

But by inspect Task Manager, I can see an app contains 100 instance of InkCanvas only take no more than 40mb memory. It is very confusing.

Comment: That is a BAD idea. Why would you ever want to create that many items? You should at least enable virtualization. Not to mention `InkCanvas` is a heavy control...

Comment: Thanks, Justin!In my working app, I've enabled virtualization. I've put them in a ListView which will dynamically create about 10 to 60 ListViewItems. But after I refresh the ListView about 3 times, the app will crashing. Got a runtime error like this.

Comment: What is each InkCanvas supposed to display?

Comment: There seem lots of "InkCanvas + out of Memory" issues. Seems InkCanvas is a heavy control, so I'll dynamically create InkCanvas only when needed and use Image to render the ink strokes. Thanks, guys! FYI:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621375/universal-windows-inkcanvas-strokes-dissapear-on-rendertargetbitmap-renderasync